# JOGL Migration Issues?

Tags: linux, opengl, nvidia, jogl

I apologise if this question is a little generic; it's quite hard to pin down.

I've created a small vector graphics application using JOGL, and ported it across four different computers running Linux Mint in conjunction with a GL2 ES 2.0 rendering environment. I render my vector graphics using the [stencil buffer technique](https://github.com/memononen/nanovg/blob/master/src/nanovg_gl.h).

The graphics have only succeeded three out of the four times, as in the fourth case, although varying colour information is retained, the curved edges of my polygons are not. This is with no change to the application code. The problematic platform's graphics card is the legacy [Nvidia Quadro NVS 440](http://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-NVIDIA/Quadro_NVS_440.html).

I'm wondering if there are any common compatibility issues that I should be looking for when migrating an OpenGL application? Or does this sound like it could potentially be a driver issue?

Comment: Are you using your own shaders? Most of my compatibility problems have come from shaders.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'm choosing to discard fragments which I originally thought would be to blame, however upon closer inspection it appears that it's the stencil buffer trick that's not quite working. 


`pGL2ES2.glStencilFunc(GL2ES2.GL_NOTEQUAL, 0, 0xFF);
   pGL2ES2.glStencilOp(GL2ES2.GL_ZERO, GL2ES2.GL_ZERO, GL2ES2.GL_ZERO);`


The parameters above should enable me to colour the 'filled' region of the vector graphics using the stencil buffer and a quad overlay, but instead shades it in entirety. Real strange issue!

Comment: Are you sure that you got a pixel format with a stencil buffer on the configuration that shows the problem?

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org The problem could be anywhere. I used a similar graphics card under Fedora several years ago and I had no trouble but maybe you don't use the same driver. Do you use "nouveau" or the proprietary driver?